# GeoServer GeoTIFF set 254 and 255 as trasparent

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'm publishing 3 band RGB GeoTIFFs via GeoServer as WMS. The WMS is added later to an OpenLayers map.

The original image has no nodata:

```
rio info dop20rgb_32806_5288_2_by-original.tif
{"blockxsize": 256, "blockysize": 256, "bounds": [806000.0, 5288000.0, 808000.0, 5290000.0], "colorinterp": ["red", "green", "blue"], "compress": "jpeg", "count": 3, "crs": "EPSG:25832", "descriptions": [null, null, null], "driver": "GTiff", "dtype": "uint8", "height": 10000, "indexes": [1, 2, 3], "interleave": "pixel", "lnglat": [13.090730968475592, 47.68139764206517], "mask_flags": [["all_valid"], ["all_valid"], ["all_valid"]], "nodata": null, "photometric": "ycbcr", "res": [0.2, 0.2], "shape": [10000, 10000], "tiled": true, "transform": [0.2, 0.0, 806000.0, 0.0, -0.2, 5290000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], "units": [null, null, null], "width": 10000}
```

Further, making a feature request to the white area around the image I can see that the white area, that should be transparent actually uses two rgb values 254 and 255.

[image]

So I've added an alpha channel like

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -srcnodata 254 -dstalpha dop20rgb_32806_5288_2_by-no255-LZW.tif dop20rgb_32806_5288_2_by-no255-LZW-alpha-2.tif
```

Which results in

[image]

What is the suggested way to either create an alpha channel that respects both (I've already tried `-srcnodata "254 255"`) or to move all 254 color to 255 to match with one value.

I would prefere to stay with GDAL or rio (rasterio)

Comment: Do you use &format=jpeg? Try &format=png instead because JPEG is lossy and creates those near original pixel values.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your reply. no openlayers requests png. But the edges are currently not of my concern but the two values that should be respectes as nodata 254, 255

Comment: GeoTIFF format supports only one nodata value. I would consider to update the source data with some raster calculator and turn 254 into 255. I guess gdal_calc could do the job. It might be possible to do that also with gdal_translate by using the -scale option.